# Getting the ID from an inserted record in SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

models.py

```
class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key = true, autoincrement=true)
  ...
```

views.py

```
entry = User()
with transaction.manager:
  DBSession.add(entry)
  DBSession.flush()
transaction.commit()
pdb.set_trace()
```

Now when I run

```
print user.id
```

I get

```
DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Userat 0x3ebc310> is not bound to a Session
```

if I change if from add to merge it just gives me

```
none
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove manual fiddling with `transaction` everything will work:

```
entry = User()
DBSession.add(entry)
DBSession.flush()
print entry.id
```

Since you're using Pyramid with ZopeTransactionExtension it is better to avoid dealing with transactions manually and leave it to Pyramid - the transaction will be committed on success and rolled back if your code raises an exception.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I thought you had to use the transaction manager for everything.